# Remove unobtrusive validation from MVC 4 template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I created a new project using the ASP.net MVC 4 Web Application template in Visual Studio 2012 (Forms Authentication) and I want to remove unobtrusive validation from it. I made the following changes:

1. Changed web.config - `add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"`
2. Changed the `BundleConfig` to remove the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script
3. I changed `_Layout` so that the jquery/jqueryval bundles were in the `<head>` section.

These are the only changes I made, but I am not getting any client side validation. When inspecting the scripts in chrome, I see jquery and `jquery.validate` (not unobtrusive) and it is not putting the unobtrusive attributes in my markup, but client side is not working at all.

What else do I need to do/undo to get rid of unobtrusive validation?

**Edit**
Inspecting the markup this is also in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
    window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[],"FormId":"form0","ReplaceValidationSummary":true,"ValidationSummaryId":"validationSummary"});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Just so I understand, you want to keep client validation, but remove the unobtrusive methods? (any reason btw?)

Comment: @Tommy No particular reason other than curiosity. Also, unobtrusive validation doesn't appear to work on dynamically added form elements without doing some extra work, so I wanted to see if I had the same issue with regular validation.

Comment: If you want to keep client side validation, you will continue to need to do more work for dynamically added fields, unobtrusive or not.  If you want just normal, POST, return view with errors, then you should be ok as long as the dynamically added elements are added to and submitted with the form

Comment: As for your issues, I would think removing the jquery validate and unobstrusive validate, forcing a complete POST and return from the server would solve your issues.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to keep client validation if possible. I was mistakenly assuming this would be easy I guess.

Comment: yeah, the challenge is going to come from having to bring over your data annotation (or however you are validating) when you dynamically add the items.  You have to give the DOM information about the properties to validate on for it work work client side.  One possible route would be to use partial views for the dynamic items (AJAX request to server to get the partial view for the element, .html(result) on the success call) then it should 'just work' without needing to do much else in wiring up the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove tags like

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.roleId)
```

Comment: Do those tags not work without unobtrusive? I guess I was under the impression that they worked with both. Do I have to manually write all the validation code as well?

Comment: if you want to disable unobtrusive validation, remove these

Comment: in answer, yeah, razor validation IS unobtrusive js. turning off unobtrusive js kills razor validation...

Comment: I am also facing same issue, I have removed these tags but then also my client side validation is not working.

Comment: @VimalPatel, you want to remove validation and still have it work?